# Internal display gets bypassed when X is started, startx

Tags: centos, xorg, nvidia

I'm running CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105, kernel: 4.18.0-305.19.1.el8_4.x86_64.  The Dell I'm using has built in Intel graphics, and an NVIDIA Quadro M1000M GPU, running with kmod-nvidia-470.74-1.el8_4.elrepo.x86_64.
Machine is a Dell precision 7510 with Xeon E3-1505M
I recently ran dnf update....[smile vanishes]

It would appear that the Intel graphics controller is just...gone.  So a separate issue, but necessary for explanation, X never started automatically after I installed the Nvidia driver.  I would boot up and drop into a terminal, log in, and have to manually execute: startx to get the desktop environment to come up; slight inconvenience but I really didn't care. Anyway, same procedure, on boot I drop into a terminal as usual and this comes up **on my laptop's internal display**; the LCD, but when I: startx, I only get video on the external display, e.g., HDMI.

output from lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6th-10th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation CM236 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107GLM [Quadro M1000M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 High Definition Audio Controller [GeForce 940MX] (rev a1)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
3d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: SK hynix PC300 NVMe Solid State Drive 512GB
```

Where is Intel VGA controller? Even more troubling in the BIOS, under system information, I see:

```
Video Controller    Error!
Video BIOS Version  Error!
Video Memory        Error!
Panel Type          Error!
Native Resolution   Error!
```

I have my Xorg.0.log and dmesg, but am not positive at the moment on how to attach these (first post here...), will figure this out and up load soon.

Things I have tried to restore the internal monitor:

```
sudo dnf history undo transaction_num # really wished that would have worked; errored with unable to locate packages
sudo dnf reinstall xorg-x11-drv-intel.x86_64 # reinstall the intel driver
sudo dnf -y reinstall `rpm -qa | egrep -i "xorg|mesa"` # reinstall all of X
sudo dnf reinstall $(rpm -qa | grep mesa) # reinstall mesa
reinstall nvidia driver
removed/renamed /etc/X11/xorg.conf to xorg.conf.BAK
```

so far nothing has worked and I am out of ideas.

**UPDATE:**

```
# xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x218 cap: 0x1, Source Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 8 associated providers: 0 name:NVIDIA-0
```

```
sudo lsmod | grep -i nv | grep -vw nvme
nvidia_drm             65536  7
nvidia_modeset       1196032  20 nvidia_drm
nvidia              35278848  1212 nvidia_modeset
drm_kms_helper        233472  1 nvidia_drm
drm                   569344  11 drm_kms_helper,nvidia,nvidia_drm
t10_pi                 16384  2 sd_mod,nvme_core
```

I also just tried clearing the CMOS, no luck.

Comment: Please add the output of `xrandr --listproviders` after you have started X11 (on HDMI). Also, look for errors (`grep EE`) in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`.

Comment: still haven't figured out a way to attach Xorg.0.log, but I can say that I do not see anything marked for error (EE) in the log.

Comment: It's enough if you say that `grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log` gives no lines of output.

Comment: Is an Nvidia kernel module loaded?  As root: `lsmod | grep -i nv | grep -vw nvme`.

Comment: Please remove the comment and edit your question instead, mark as code - button "{}".